# git checkout tries to checkout commit rather than branch

Tags: git

In my repository, I have a branch named `1348` and a commit with a hash code that begins with `1348`.

When I execute `git checkout 1348`, git switches me to the commit. How can I specify to switch to branch rather than commit?

`git version` shows the following:

> git version 2.7.5

Comment: On my system, `git checkout 403d` (while having a branch named `403d` and a commit named `403dc38ef5b0ad9b102aca7159c2a77840f4ac2d`) gives me `warning: refname '403d' is ambiguous. Switched to branch '403d'`. Git version 2.14.1.

Comment: What version of Git are you using? On version 2.14.1, I get `warning: refname '5961' is ambiguous.` [5961 is the similar example I constructed], but it does switch to the branch rather than the commit whose SHA has that prefix.

Comment: git version 2.7.5

Comment: But sometimes I also have this warning that still successfully switches me to branch. Today was the first time when git decided to choose a commit.

Comment: A simple workaround is to name your branches differently, e.g. `v1348` or `r1348`.

Comment: @Thomas yes, this would work, but I would like to avoid this if possible, so still looking for solution.

Comment: @Boris to avoid this you should never use only numeric characters to name your branches :), you should think of meaningful names (release/something, bugfix/something, feature/something...)

Comment: Looks like you just need to update your git version.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, git looks for a branch first and only interprets the argument as a SHA prefix if no branch is found.  So two possibilities:

1) This behavior may have changed between the version you're using and now; in that case, you could upgrade git versions.

2) Is it possible you're mistaken about the branch existing with exactly this name?

There is no argument to specifically tell git that you mean the branch.